# Python. Не понимаю поведение .append в цикле

Tags: python, append

товарищи!
Собственно код:

```
K = [[0 for x in range(capacity+1)] for x in range(2)]
S = []
# DP
for i in range(item_count+1):
    for c in range(capacity+1):
        if i == 0 or c == 0:
            K[i % 2][c] = 0
            if c == capacity:
                S.append(K[i % 2])
        elif weights[i-1] <= c:
            K[i % 2][c] = max(
                values[i-1]+K[(i - 1) % 2][c-weights[i-1]], 
                K[(i - 1) % 2][c])
            if c == capacity:
                S.append(K[i % 2])
        else:
            K[i % 2][c] = K[(i - 1) % 2][c]
value = K[item_count % 2][capacity]
print(S)
```

Ожидаю что в каждом цикле в S будет добавляться текущая запись K[i % 2], таким образом в результате получу матрицу S в которой будут все K[i % 2] из цикла.
Однако вижу, что S не просто увеличивается с каждым циклом, а какие-то записи удаляются.
Просьба подсказать из-за чего такое поведение программы?

Пример:
На первом цикле, когда i=0, c=capacity в S добавляется строка:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Далее добавляется строка:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

Но вот потом вместо того, чтобы добавить третью строку при новом i, S приобретает следующий вид:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 18, 18, 18]  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

Ну и при слебующем i:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 18, 18, 18]  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 10, 10, 10, 15, 18, 18, 18]  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 18, 18, 18]
```

**Как так?**

Comment: Ну вы же добавляете в `S` ссылки на списки внутри `K`, а потом меняете эти списки внутри `K`. Вот эти изменения и отражаются в `S`.

Comment: `S.append(K[i % 2])` -> `S.append(K[i % 2][:])`. Перед тем как вставлять элемент `K` делайте его копию.

Comment: что такое weights, capacity, item_count?

Comment: Не зная в чём суть задачи и какое ожидается поведение вообще сложно что-то советовать

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Stanislav Volodarskiy!
Проблема была в том, что вставлял ссылку, а не само значение.

```
S.append(K[i % 2]) -> S.append(K[i % 2][:])
```

Comment: Так тоже ссылка, но копии=)